# Remove item from SharedPreference when removed from Listview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my code, with the help of context menu I'm able to delete a particular item from Listview but as I'm using sharedpreferences to save arraylist called "places" then it restores the sharedpreference when the app is launched back again. Now how should I implement my sharedpreferences such that when a particular item is deleted from listview, the same item also gets deleted from arraylist "places" of shared preferences.

Below is my code snippet

```
static ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList<>();   //to save lat and long
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    public ListView listView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.starprojects.memorableplaces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);

        //tricker locations
        ArrayList<String> latitudes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> longitudes = new ArrayList<>();

        //initially set
        places.clear();
        latitudes.clear();
        longitudes.clear();
        locations.clear();


        //to restore
        try {

            places = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));

            latitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("latitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));

            longitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("longitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));

            Log.i("palces",places.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

          AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
         // sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("places",0);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            if((item.getTitle()).equals("Delete"))
            {
                places.remove(info.position);

                editor.remove("places");   //problem is here, how to get particular index to be removed from arraylist places and save it.
                editor.commit();

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get index by

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
int index = info.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

it means you must a list in you shared preference or you have a different key for your shared preference.

**Case 1:** if you have a list in your shared preference than update the shared preference with the remove of data of data from the listview.

**Case 2:** if you assigned different key_names for each of the list item then you can simply remove or clear that key_name when the data is removed from the shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the point of your question you are trying to keep the shared preferences copy up to date with the one you display and vice-versa.
To accomplish this I think that you just need to put the updated places array list into shared preferences, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

  if ((item.getTitle()).equals("Delete")) {

      // Update local list
      places.remove(info.position);

      // Set list into shared preferences
      // Or if you use a JSON string you could serialize and use putString()
      editor.putStringSet("places", places);

      // Use apply it's async
      editor.apply();

      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      return true;
  }

  return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please use apply() in place of commit(). [It's faster and asynchronous](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Comment: what i'm trying to do here is that there is an arraylist called Places, so when i remove an element from it by deleting places.remove(info.position) then it should be deleted from the sharedpreferences as well.

Comment: If places has {Add new location,xyz,abc}; so if i delete abc then sharedpreference should also delete it. But what is happening with my code is that when I delete it gets deleted as local change but when I restart the app after killing it, it comes back as it is being saved in sharedpreference

Comment: Ok that's what I got, I think that my example will fix your problem. By the way you should consider moving to a persistent storage like a database to store the places. It'll be easier to manage

Comment: i'm just learning, btw i got the solution myself. I'll be updating my answer soon.

Comment: Ok, if you need further explaining on my example, basically every time I remove something from places, then I immediately update the places object into shared preferences setting with the current places arraylist.